# Is it possible to output STATISTICS IO and TIME to grid or a table?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Table] WHERE [Timestamp] < '1.2.1980')
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(1000) FROM [Table] WHERE [Timestamp] < '1.2.1980'
END

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

This writes the statistics IO and TIME to Messages window. But the amount of messages in Message windows is big because the DELETE is performed aprox. 700 times.

Is it possible to redirect the output to grid or even table? So it will be possible to analyze the output and get e.g. complete CPU time for all the DELETES. Or is it possible to get one summary statistic for all the 700 DELETES?

Comment: I'm literally looking to do the same thing today, but more to log unit tests between slow/fast views. Have you tried http://statisticsparser.com/ by the way? You can paste in the `STATISTICS IO, TIME` output and it formats and summarises all the data.